# Neo4J : How to Order results by attributes value

Tags: sorting, neo4j, cypher

How do I order my results using Node properties value using Cypher Queries?

For Example :
I have the below results :

| Person | City |
| --- | --- |
| Kasper | London |
| Sean | Chicago |
| Tom | London |
| Kate | New York |
| John | London |
| Sarah | Chicago |

I want to sort the above result on basis of "London" i.e people from London should be on top. The sorted results can look something like this :

| Person | City |
| --- | --- |
| Kasper | London |
| John | London |
| Tom | London |
| Kate | New York |
| Sean | Chicago |
| Sarah | Chicago |

I know Order By clause can be used to sort in ascending or descending order but can we use it to sort on the basis of Value? If not, please suggest some other way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to do custom ordering, you need to provide custom properties of the cities to let you order by

Answer (score 0):

you can sort by property value . imagine `(p:Person)` and `(c:City)` nodes

```
RETURN p.name AS Person, c.name AS City
ORDER BY City
```

another example

```
WITH p,c
ORDER BY p.birthdate
RETURN p.name AS Person, c.name AS City
```

in case you want to order by age.

if your cities have to be in an order based on a specific property, add e.g.  `index` to the city node , and do something like:

```
WITH p,c
ORDER BY c.index
RETURN p.name AS Person, c.name AS City
```

Comment: That will not put "London" on top of the results. It will order the Cities lexicographically.

Comment: so you have in your city nodes some arbitrary property that indicates the order ? in that case, you could use it in the same way as the birth date. i will expand my answer.